How to clean coal dust stains off an untreated antique pine shelf in a wardrobe?
I have inherited an old farmhouse style pine wardrobe. Buckets of coal used to be stored inside. The untreated pine shelf is now covered in black coal dust stains.
How can I remove this coal dust staining without damaging the wood?
The shelf cannot be removed, and the bottom of the cupboard also has some stains from buckets placed there.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. How clean do you want it to end up? Is just sufficiently clean that anything placed on it doesn't get dirty enough or do you want it to be pristine? You can actually wash wood and this would be my main suggestion, but to do it effectively you really need to remove the shelf from the inside of the wardrobe for a couple of reasons. So first, can the shelf be removed? First step though might not be obvious and that's literally just brushing it down dry, even vacuuming it. I doubt these will be enough to make the wood look pristine but it'll be massively cleaner.

Is the shelf a plain board that just sits on supports BTW? If the underside is perfectly clean just flipping it over might be an option :-)

Thank you for replying.   The shelf cannot be removed, and the bottom of the cupboard has also got the coal dust staining (inside the cupboard, buckets were put on this too).   If I clean the untreated pine, I do not know what product to use as I don't want to damage the wood.

I tend to use Murphy's Oil Soap (with warm water) when I want to clean wood things.  It won't damage the wood as long as when you are done you let everything dry.  I'd start by making sure you have done the easier cleaning first, dust/vacuum, etc.   Otherwise you'll have to move on to sanding...

Ok to start with I suggest you go into this not expecting the wood to end up looking pristine and unmarked. However you most certainly can expect to get the wood surface clean enough that you don't need to worry about dirt transfer to clean fabrics placed on them. Just cleaning dry might accomplish this.
So first step should either be dry dusting or brushing off. It may be ideal to use a vacuum cleaner and one of the brush heads for this if you have enough access. If you don't I'd suggest making use of a microfibre cloth.
If you've done nothing at all yet you might be pleasantly surprised at how much this step alone improves the appearance.
Next step would be washing. As mentioned in the Comments, you can literally wash wood (which shouldn't really surprise us given wooden kitchen implements, salad bowls and cutting boards are all regularly washed, and in some households daily).
Here's a basic outline of how you might go about this.

Prepare a pan of soapy water. Warm would usually be preferred for cleaning, but this will "raise the grain" more than cold water (more on raised grain below).

It really doesn't matter much what form the soap takes, it could be dishwashing liquid, a proprietary cleaning soap (liquid or solid), or hand soaps (nearly anything1). I've tried them all, and as far as the wood is concerned it literally seems to make no difference at all.

Rinse off afterwards with clean water. If you want to be thorough do this twice with clean water each time, although once could be perfectly fine.

Now dry the wood down with dry towels rather than leaving it fully wet to dry on its own. This will help to minimise the chance of warping2, particularly if you can't equally wet both sides of the boards you're working on. The wood will take between four and 12 hours to fully dry so just go ahead and wait overnight.


Getting the wood wet is likely to raise the grain, even with wood this old (you can get this on wooden surfaces well over a century old, depending on whether they've been wet before). This "raised grain" leaves a rough and prickly surface. It is easily rectified with only light abrasion.
Removing raised grain and further sanding
With pine especially you may be able to get the wood smooth enough just by scrubbing down using the coarser side of brown paper, or scraps of cardboard from stout boxes.
However you might want to go ahead and sand anyway to make the wood even cleaner. If you choose to, this will of course sand off any raised grain while you're at it.
There is much advice here and of course elsewhere online on how to sand wood if you need further tips. But for something basic like this using only a single grit that's neither too coarse nor too fine may be sufficient. 150 may be the sweet spot here. If you want to be slightly more efficient, start at 80 grit or maybe 100, and then switch to 150. Although you can sand to much higher grits there's really no need.
Remove dust frequently as you go, this helps abrasive papers to cut more efficiently and for something like this minimises dirty dust being worked into the wood surface.
If you sand sufficiently you can expect to get the wood looking flawless. But if you sand exclusively by hand (absolutely doable for a single project like this) just very clean is an easier target to hit.
Remove the last traces of dust using a clean, dry, microfibre cloth and you're done.

1 But perhaps not anything strongly coloured or with 'bits' in it :-)
2 Please note however that there IS a chance of some warp occurring, probably most likely on the shelf. It should not be excessive, however it is unlikely you'll be able to undo it.
